Application not working with Cloudflare Challenges
I'm trying to increase Cloudflare security, but I'm having trouble handling the challenge and retrieving cookies in flutter.
I created an empty application to avoid dependency issues in my project. This application only has 1 button that makes the request.
When the return status code is 403, I open an InAppWebView with the returned HTML content and the URL. The InAppWebView does the job correctly and I can capture the Cloudflare cookies correctly.
When I make a new request, I already have the cookie and set it to the request header. And even so, I get a 403 return. But if I make the same request via CURL, I get a 200 return. As if the problem was with Flutter.
I'm using the http request lib, I've already used dio and got the same result.
void _actionconsultaragenda(BuildContext context) async {

    var body = """
  {
    "inicio": "2024-12-29 00:00:00",
    "fim": "2025-01-04 23:59:59",
    "funcionarios" : null,
    "idEmpresa" : "8",
    "showBloqueios": true
}
""";

    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      "User-Agent":"AgendaDEV", //usamos isso para forçar o CHALLANGE
    };

    headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer 23542963-393e-4218-9421-c6782e545cca';
    headers['countryCode'] = 'BR';
    headers['languageCode'] = 'pt';
    headers['language'] = 'pt-BR';
    
    // só vai entrar aqui na segunda vez
    if (StaticClass.COOKIES != null) {
      headers['Cookie'] = StaticClass.COOKIES!;
    }
    
    log("Headers::::::");
    log('Cookie: ${headers['Cookie']}');

    var url = "https://urlcomcloudflare.com/api/agenda/consulta";

    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: body, headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      log("Retornou 200 OK");
    } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
      log("Retornou 403");
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => Handler(response.body, url)));
    } else {
      log("Ué Retornou ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }

When I get the cookie, it is sent in this format:

When I make the same request with curl:
#!/bin/bash

# Defina a URL da API e os cabeçalhos
URL='https://urlcomcloudflare.com/api/agenda/consulta'
USER_AGENT='AgendaDEV'
CONTENT_TYPE='application/json'
AUTHORIZATION='Bearer 23542963-393e-4218-9421-c6782e545cca'
# COOKIE=''
COOKIE='cf_clearance=hyQQzGTJp2BdtcEasTGN1DxsjU3lSsS1aE6IQl9Uip8-1732743093-1.2.1.1-ETF9sXitoNyrTSIOn9wuQ_BWtjLXAp2DAzQWUemDPxDwZ21o.uyTfM06FM6iun1i_4IC1oYzih1WauURrYuN6aP1xw3vPTXuujiuTRo9NKXNktRw1Sh3rb6XO4VQcTwkDX89l8GkwdF5pAMT2W.sbvwHGPbANoRSleU4qe4vch1lN0_3JJs76dskNi_vYT2LnqDDWqkQXtq1dstYTmVkZQQZx4imwxY3tkvY6pj2vZQhvo9xGuC_gUZxSYzb2EnEI0VgbWXZIdD5JFEkPUx3vvTLKpOber6JnwDjTRF7nT8OoUQPyfQFOhd9MlGgMNkZ; cf_chl_rc_ni=2; JSESSIONID=D9E4611FE71C8081FCD0FC1634FE788F'

# Corpo da requisição em JSON
DATA='{
    "inicio": "2024-12-29 00:00:00",
    "fim": "2025-01-04 23:59:59",
    "funcionarios" : null,
    "idEmpresa" : "8",
    "showBloqueios": true
}'

curl -X POST --location "$URL" \
         --header "User-Agent: $USER_AGENT" \
         --header "Content-Type: $CONTENT_TYPE" \
         --header "authorization: $AUTHORIZATION" \
         --header "Cookie: $COOKIE" \
         --header "languagecode: pt" \
         --header "countrycode: BR" \
         --header "language: pt-BR" \
         --data "$DATA"

